# Select a row having a column with max value - On a date range

Tags: sql, oracle

Excuse me for posting a similar question. Please consider this:

```
date                 value

18/5/2010, 1 pm        40
18/5/2010, 2 pm        20
18/5/2010, 3 pm        60
18/5/2010, 4 pm        30
18/5/2010, 5 pm        60
18/5/2010, 6 pm        25 
19/5/2010, 6 pm        300 
19/5/2010, 6 pm        450 
19/5/2010, 6 pm        375 
20/5/2010, 6 pm        250 
20/5/2010, 6 pm        310
```

The query is to get the date and value for **each day** such that the value obtained for that day is max. If the max value is repeated on that day, the lowest time stamp is selected. The result should be like:

```
18/5/2010, 3 pm        60
19/5/2010, 6 pm        450
20/5/2010, 6 pm        310
```

The query should take in a date range like the one given below and find results for that range in the above fashion:

where
    date >= to_date('26/03/2010','DD/MM/YYYY') AND
    date < to_date('27/03/2010','DD/MM/YYYY')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you provide a CREATE TABLE and INSERT, it makes it a lot easier to provide a tested answer.

```
create table i (i_dt date, i_val number);

insert into i values (to_date('18/5/2010 1pm','dd/mm/yyyy hham'),        40);
insert into i values (to_date('18/5/2010 2pm','dd/mm/yyyy hham'),        20);
insert into i values (to_date('18/5/2010 3pm','dd/mm/yyyy hham'),        60);
insert into i values (to_date('18/5/2010 4pm','dd/mm/yyyy hham'),        30);
insert into i values (to_date('18/5/2010 5pm','dd/mm/yyyy hham'),        60);
insert into i values (to_date('18/5/2010 6pm','dd/mm/yyyy hham'),        25 );
insert into i values (to_date('19/5/2010 6pm','dd/mm/yyyy hham'),        300 );
insert into i values (to_date('19/5/2010 6pm','dd/mm/yyyy hham'),        450 );
insert into i values (to_date('19/5/2010 6pm','dd/mm/yyyy hham'),        375 );
insert into i values (to_date('20/5/2010 6pm','dd/mm/yyyy hham'),        250 );
insert into i values (to_date('20/5/2010 6pm','dd/mm/yyyy hham'),        310 );

select i_dt, i_val from 
   (select i.*, rank() over (partition by trunc(i_dt) order by i_val desc, i_dt asc) rn 
   from i) 
where rn = 1;
```

Answer (score 2):

You are aggregating your data, so use grouping and aggregation functions. You can add any where clause you want, but I copied your where clause in, changing the dates so every record is selected. Borrowing Gary's create table and insert statements:

```
SQL> select min(i_dt) keep (dense_rank last order by i_val) i_dt
  2       , max(i_val) i_val
  3    from i
  4   where i_dt >= to_date('26/03/2010','dd/mm/yyyy')
  5     and i_dt < to_date('27/05/2010','dd/mm/yyyy')
  6   group by trunc(i_dt)
  7  /

I_DT                     I_VAL
------------------- ----------
18-05-2010 15:00:00         60
19-05-2010 18:00:00        450
20-05-2010 18:00:00        310

3 rows selected.
```

Regards,
Rob.

Comment: Thank you. How would I change this query to get this:

18-05-2010 15:00:00         60
18-05-2010 17:00:00         60
19-05-2010 18:00:00        450
20-05-2010 18:00:00        310

Comment: Can you please edit your question or start a new one, and include an explanation with your new output. Because this comment confuses me.

Answer (score 0):

I've not tried this, but I would think you want something like:

```
select max(date)
from  table
where date >= to_date('26/03/2010','DD/MM/YYYY') AND date < to_date('27/03/2010','DD/MM/YYYY')
group by trunc(date)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But, when I use this query for the date range having more than 1 day:

where date >= to_date('18/03/2010','DD/MM/YYYY') AND date < to_date('21/03/2010','DD/MM/YYYY')

It will give the max value considering all three days in the given range and not for each day.